# How can I access the logfiles from Skype in Android?

Tags: android, skype

I want to parse through the skype log files, how can I access the log of the Skype app on Android? 
Second question:
What format do the logs have?

Comment: you got any solution ??
Plz let me know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if skype saves the format in its local folder, from android 2.1 and above, you can't have access to it. Except if you root your phone.

Skype is well known for not documenting much. I really don't believe their logs, or anything else would be open.